How to seed data immediately after creating table in Django
On running makemigrations command in Django, the migration files are created, which can be manually edited before running the migrate command (I do it to change order of columns). I am creating a reference table with this process, which I also want to immediately seed. I am writing a custom command for this seed_common (reading from a CSV and saving into table a row at a time, as I have to do some preprocessing per row). Is there a way where I can run the code of seeding when the migrate command is executed - even though it means I have manually call it from the nnnn_initial.py file? I know running one more command for seeding might not be a big deal, but I just want to simplify documentation for environment creation, so would like to merge commands if possible.

See data migrations

You can add your code in migration file only like following.
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '0001_initial.py'),
    ]

    """
     # your existing fields related code which is automatically generated.
    """


    def func_to_read_csv(apps, schema_editor):
        # your code


    

    operations = [
       "automatic migration 1" ,
       "automatic migration 2",
        migrations.RunPython(
            func_to_read_csv
        )
    ]

in operations array you would have some code already just add another migrations.RunPython(func_to_read_csv) in that array.
your function will do it's work when you ll do python manage.py migrate

To keep migration file separate, I found one more way. Run py manage.py makemigrations --name=somename --empty appname. This creates an empty template appname/migrations/nnnn_somename.py, which I can edit to add stuff similar to the answer above.
